What is the best practice on importing packages for functions in a multi-file project
I have a multi-file project, where I have one main file and import almost all necessary functions from other files. Some of these functions require certain packages.
I would import all packages at the beginning of the main file, but then the functions I am importing do not work without being imported in the main file. Is this considered bad practice? If so, what would be the best way to implement this?

Why not import in files that actually need those imports?

Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you're trying to describe?  It's not clear to me what stops you from importing whatever you need to import.

What I see in your case is the missing/lack of proper project organization. In a professional python project, not all the files included in the project are executable ones. There could be readme.md or requirement.txt files that enhance the readability and understanding of the code while giving the reader information about the possible of relationship/dependencies of one file on another.
Your question falls in the correct organization of the project files. What I would suggest is to not any import/include any package in the main file. The correct place of importing package is where you are using them. Or if you are not comfortable with that, you need to include the file in the main file as given in the example below.
from module1 import function_a
from module2 import function_b

# Main logic
function_a()
function_b()

where module1.py could be defined in following way
import numpy as np  # Import only what is needed

def function_a():
  print(np.array([1, 2, 3]))

and module2.py as
import pandas as pd  # Import only what is needed

def function_b():
    print(pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]}))

and so on. And finally to remind yourself and others which packages you have included, you can include a requirement.txt that could look something like this
numpy
panda
...


I was under the impression that this wouldn't work, because I got errors when doing it like that so I assumed when importing the function, the imports it needs, need to be inside the function, but this is not the case.
